# Remove trailing white space from vue.js router-link

Tags: vue.js

Text in router-link always has a trailing white space after.
Which make it to not align in the center, How to remove it???

Test Code

```
<div class="DesktopHeaderView">
        <router-link to="/">
            Test
        </router-link>
</div>
```

[image: test]

This is my real code

```
<div class="DesktopHeaderView">
        <router-link
            class="DesktopHeaderView__link"
            active-class="active"
            exact
            v-for="(view, index) in views"
            :key="index"
            :to="view.to"
        >
            {{ view.text }}
        </router-link>
</div>
```

[image: trailing spaces]

Note: There is no trailing spaces in the text field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I somehow managed to solve this by wrapping the text by span tag

```
<div class="DesktopHeaderView">
        <router-link
            class="DesktopHeaderView__link"
            active-class="active"
            exact
            v-for="(view, index) in views"
            :key="index"
            :to="view.to"
        >
            <span>{{ view.text }}</span>
        </router-link>
</div>
```

[image]

No more trailing spaces
But still have no idea why it behaves like this

Answer (score 0):

Try with javascript  trim()  `view.text.trim()`

Comment: It doesn't work. I added a sample code to see a clearer picture of the problem.

Comment: You probably have to make a `ul` list with links inside. I was reading this article https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=css-removing-extra-space-between-inline-block-elements-using-zer . Also you could try setting padding and margin to 0 to the `a` element.